# Php page protection for cron task only

Tags: php, jquery, security, cron, jobs

I am using linux cpanel shared hosting.

Am using `http://aaa.com/script.php` to scrape data from other website.

PHP portion is to curl call to read whole page content, then on the page, will output the full content as html, then use jquery scrapping & ajax call to insert final data into mysql.

(I decided to go for jquery client side scrapping because the page with html to scrap is pretty complicated, and hard to achieve with phpsimpledom and regex.)

I want this page to stop outputting html when it is 
- not open by me as a tester
- not open by local cpanel cron task.

So I put `exit();` at the top few lines.
If detected is legitimate, then will continue the rest of the html outputs at bottom, else, just exit and show an empty page.

Now is security issue, what's the possible and best way for me to make sure other visitors/bots to this page will see empty page.

If I put a password to cron task, I don't think it can work right?
Because at script.php I am scrapping data, so if the website owner see the visitor referral log, he can see the full url including ?password=12345, isn't it.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/mysite/public_html/dir/script.php?password=12345
```

If I put my script outside of public_html, like `/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/mysite/script` 
I don't think it will work for jquery, it is purely for php isn't it?

What else I can do??

Comment: How do you expect a script that uses jQuery and AJAX in a web browser to work as a cron job?

Comment: You found the page difficult to scrape with a PHP parse and you used jQuery instead? :o

Comment: hi Russell, yes. Jquery dom selector make things easy to get done.

Comment: You do realize you can with DomDocument + XPath to acheive the same selector funcionality.

Comment: Yes, but not easy to achieve. Eg: to scrap a page with full of small nested tables inside big table and having a lot of colspan rowspan. Sometimes the page to scrap is even html not well formatted.

Comment: and you of course have permission to scrape this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords on the query string are a bad idea. You could check for valid IP addresses at the start of your PHP file. This will allow any request from a set of IP addresses to access the parsed jQuery output. All other IPs will be denied access.

```
$allowedIps = array('127.0.0.1','::1');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowedIps)){
    echo 'No jQuery for you';
}else{
    echo 'jQuery goodness to follow...';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could config apache's virtual host to only allow access from your ip.
Anyone else would get a 404 page not found or 403 permission denied depending how you configured it.

Here's a sample

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Using 127.0.0.1 tells apache to let requests from itself (ie cron) to work but noone else.

You get learn more by reading the apache2 docs